# Summa Theologiae - se extendit

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, reflexive-pronoun, aquinas

Summa Theologiae, Ia q. 14 a. 11 co.:

> Et ideo aliter dicendum est, quod, cum Deus sit causa rerum per suam scientiam, ut dictum est, intantum **se extendit** scientia Dei, inquantum **se extendit** eius causalitas

What is the effect of **se**, which comes before **extendit**, on the meaning of sentence and is it omittable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb extendere is transitive, meaning it expects a direct object. The verb means to prolong, spread out, or extend something. So, the *se* here makes the verb reflexive. The *scientia Dei* isn't spreading something else out; but rather it is itself spread out so that it extends over a (metaphorical) area.

We could translate the last portion this way: the scope of God's knowledge is equal to the scope of his causality.

Or: God's causality extends as far as his knowledge.